# Green Formula in weighted space

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Working with Green identities, I was wondering if they are dependent of the chosen coordinate system ? If you use cylindrical coordinates, your metric changes but do you still have regular Green formula ?

Comment: The general formulas do not change but what is meant by gradient and Laplacian changes.

Comment: Very good comment. I'd make this an answer.

Comment: @EricAuld Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formulas do not change but what is meant but gradient and Laplacian change in different coordinate systems.